# Razor page, server code with html

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I can't figure out how to mix html with server code in this scenario.

```
@{ 
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var match in Model.StagingRooms)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            <div class="row">
        }
        Html.Partial("_MatchCard", match.Value);
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Using the code above, instead of rows of cards, I get an output of my code.
[image]

If I add @ to Html.Partial and the increment
[image]

I also tried to append @ to each server code line, and removing the @{} block, however this doesn't let me compile at all. I get a bunch of red squiggles in my code.

Edit:
When I add @ to every server code snippet then I get squiggles, and can't compile
[image]
If I remove @ from the last if statement, then I can run the app, but that piece of code is displayed back to me in the browser page.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried @foreach

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an @ here: `@Html.Partial(....)`.

Also `@foreach` and `@if`, as Brad said.

And code lines go in brackets: `@(i++)`

Comment: That doesn't work. I changed the code a bit since my original post, but the concept is the same, so I'll attach a few screens to show what that does.